# Show children in Mat Tree from dynamic data backend

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need your help about Mat Tree with dynamic Data and lazy loading.
I have found this example here from Angular https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-dynamic-example.ts
But I have a different structure of data.
I can see the parent but unable to load the children.
The parent it is an Object itself like this.

```
{
   "description":"Test Purpose",
   "childDevices":8,
   "childLocations":8,
   "name":"Test",
   "id":"1234556788www2"
}
```

Then to load more information or children for this I need to create an Get request which gives me back like this.

```
{
    "id": "1234556788www2",
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test Purpose",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [
        "1st Child ID",
        "2nd Child ID"
    ],
    "groupsV2": [
        "group ID"
    ],
    "usersV2": [
        "userID"
    ],
    "tenantId": "Tenant ID",
    "devices": [
        "device1 ID",
        "device2 ID",
        "device3 ID",
        "device4 ID"
    ]
}
```

Now to get its children I need to iterate again through API Get so I can get information about each children and then to show on tree under the parent. I have spent a lot of hours and did not find how to show the children into the tree.
This is the JSON for each children.

```
{
    "id": "1st Child ID",
    "name": "TestLocation",
    "description": "333",
    "parent": "1234556788www2",
    "children": [],
    "groupsV2": [
       
    ],
    "usersV2": [
       
    ],
    "tenantId": "",
    "devices": []
}
```

This is my HTML.

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" data-cy="locationsMatTree">
          <mat-tree-node>
            <mat-nested-tree-node
              *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild"
              [class.hidden]="!node.visible"
              [class.fe-action]="node.overallFEChildCount > 0"
              [class.be-action]="node.overallFEChildCount < node.overallChildCount">
              <div class="title mat-tree-node on-hover">
                <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle *ngIf="node.childLocations > 0; else noLocations">
                  <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror" (click)="loadChildren(node)">
                    {{ treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right' }}
                  </mat-icon>
                </button>
                <ng-template #noLocations>
                  <button mat-icon-button>
                    <mat-icon class="no-sub-icon">
                      <span class="leaf-icon"> • </span>
                    </mat-icon>
                  </button>
                </ng-template>
                <div
                  class="location-name hide-in-percy"
                  (click)="loadDevices(node)"
                  [routerLink]="['/location/details', node.id]"
                  [id]="'created-' + node.name">
                  {{ node.name }}
                </div>
                <icon-button
                  color="primary"
                  *ngIf="!isDisabled"
                  iconName="add"
                  type="mat-icon-button"
                  class="action-button action-button-add"
                  (click)="onNewClicked(node)">
                </icon-button>
                <icon-button
                  color="primary"
                  type="mat-icon-button"
                  iconName="edit"
                  class="action-button action-button-edit"
                  (click)="onEditClicked(node)">
                </icon-button>
                <icon-button
                  color="warn"
                  type="mat-icon-button"
                  iconName="delete"
                  class="action-button action-button-delete"
                  [disabled]="node.action?.generated"
                  [matTooltipDisabled]="!node.action?.generated"
                  matTooltip="{{ 'RIGHT_ACTIONS_DISABLED_LEAF' | translate }}"
                  (click)="deleteLocation(node)">
                </icon-button>
              </div>
              <ul [class.tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
                <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
              </ul>
              <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="node.isLoading" mode="indeterminate" class="example-tree-progress-bar"></mat-progress-bar>
            </mat-nested-tree-node>
          </mat-tree-node>
        </mat-tree>
```

TS Code.

```
 private readonly subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<Location>();
  hasChild = (_: number, node: Location) => !!node.childLocations && node.childLocations > 0;



 this.locationService
      .getLocationsForUser(this.pageIndex, this.pageSize)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.dataSource.data = response.body.content; // here I load all parents
        this.flatLocations = this.getFlatLocations();
        this.length = response.body.totalElements;

        if (response.body.content && response.body.content.length > 0) {
          this.location = response.body.content[0];
          this.loadDevices(this.location);
        }

        this.subscribeToRouteParams();
      });
  }


 loadChildren = (location: Location): any => {
    this.locationService.getLocation(location.id).subscribe((res) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < res.body.children.length; i++) {
        this.locationService.getLocation(res.body.children[i]).subscribe((t) => {
          return of(t.body); //Here I can see each child data
         });
      }
    });
    return false;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is currently that you are nesting subscriptions in your `loadChildren` function. You probably want to use `switchMap` and `forkJoin` to make the calls to `this.locationService.getLocation()` in parallel and output the response of each call in an array:

```
loadChildren = (location: Location): any => {
    this.locationService.getLocation(location.id).pipe(
      switchMap(res => forkJoin(
        res.body.children.map(child => this.locationService.getLocation(child))
        )
      )
    ).subscribe( resultArray => {
      location.childLocations = resultArray;
    });
}
```